# Regular expression, find all occurrence of the result (group)

Tags: regex, tmlanguage

I have this regular expression:

```
(?i)((\w+\s+)(?=\s*IN\s+|\s*IN\s+OUT\s+|(?<!IN\s)(?=\s*OUT\s+)))
```

That find every string followed by '***in***', '***in out***' and '***out***'.
In this exemple:

```
 function myNestedProc(param1 in varchar2,
                       param2 out number)
    return varchar2
  is
  begin
    return param1||'_TEST';
  end;
```

I highlight ***param1*** in varchar2 and ***param2*** out number, 
but no *return *param1*||'_TEST'*.
How can I capture all words equal to those captured by regular expression?

Comment: Here is a live playground with that regex and test case: https://regex101.com/r/jQDBrf/1. Answerers can use that tool while trying to figure out the solution.

Comment: If you want to include the ||'_TEST part, change it to `(?i)((\w+)(?=\s+IN\s+|\s+IN\s+OUT\s+|(?<!IN\s)\s+OUT\s+|\s*\|\|\s*'?_TEST))`

Comment: And if you want to _see_ what the assertion qualifies it, it's `(?i)((\w+)(?=(\s+IN\s+|\s+IN\s+OUT\s+|(?<!IN\s)\s+OUT\s+|\s*\|\|\s*'?_TEST)))` https://regex101.com/r/P1O2x2/1

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: I want to capture every other occurrence of param1 and param2 
Which were previously captured.

Comment: It is a tmLanguage